# i cant import the JDL file

Tags: jhipster

while importing :

C:\Users\SYBInfo\Desktop\STAGEE>jhipster import-jdl C:\Users\SYBInfo\Desktop\Final.jh

C:\Users\SYBInfo\Desktop\STAGEE>

whithout any change, any errors and any results

Comment: Hi sarah Welcome to SO please update your question with specific details and must read this first https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you tried running `jhipster --debug import-jdl ....` to collect more information? Please edit your question to paste your JDL. Does `jhipster info`work ?